# Как в одном vuex модуле вызвать мутацию из другого модуля?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Доброго времени суток.

Есть два Vuex модуля А и B. В модуле А переменная pickupUserDelivery получает из промиса информацию о созданной доставке. Нужно вызвать мутацию из модуля B, которая установит только что созданную доставку как выбранную для пользователя.

Экшен из модуля А:

```
        @Action({ rawError: true })
        async savePickup (userDelivery: Pickup): Promise<void> {
                const pickupUserDelivery = await ctx.app.$api.delivery.createUserDeliveryPickup(userDelivery.getParams());
                // Тут я пытался вызвать мутацию, но оно так не работает 
                // this.context.commit('setSelectedUserDeliveryId', pickupUserDelivery.id, {root:true});
        }
```

Мутация, которая находится в модуле B:

```
        @Mutation
        setSelectedUserDeliveryId (userDeliveryId: number | null) {
            this._selectedShipmentTemplateId = userDeliveryId;
        }
```

Уже второй день бьюсь - не могу понять как это сделать ><

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем я разобрался.

Нужно было всего лишь добавить название модуля к мутации, чтобы получилась следующая конструкция:

```js
this.context.commit('{название модуля}/{мутация}', { переменная }, { root:true });
```